# Yii2: How to set db console migration parameter as array

Tags: yii2, console, migration

I want to migrate my test database using the command migrate/fresh --db=array as stated by the help:

```
--db: Connection|array|string
  the DB connection object or the application component ID of the DB connection to use
  when applying migrations. Starting from version 2.0.3, this can also be a configuration array
  for creating the object.
```

but I don't know how to specify an array in the command line.

I have tried the following command:

```
  php yii migrate/fresh --db="dns=sqlite:@app/runtime/test.db"
```

but I get

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\db\Connection::0'
```

Having a look at console/Controller/runAction:

```
                if (in_array($name, $options, true)) {
                    $default = $this->$name;
                    if (is_array($default)) {
                        $this->$name = preg_split('/\s*,\s*(?![^()]*\))/', $value);
                    } elseif ($default !== null) {
                        settype($value, gettype($default));
                        $this->$name = $value;
                    } else {
                        $this->$name = $value;
                    }
```

It looks like $this->db should be initaliced as an array if I want to be able to pass an array from the command line.

However, even if I set it as an array, the preg_split command indexes the configuracion array for the connection by number, not by an string key, so this array can not create a db connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure it from console in this way. This description comes from [`$db`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-console-controllers-migratecontroller#$db-detail) property documentation, which is valid (`MigrateController` will handle array with configuration or `Connection` instance), but it is possible to define these formats only from PHP - from console you can pass only string.

If you really need to define connection dynamically from PHP, you can override [`MigrateController::beforeAction()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-console-controllers-migratecontroller#beforeAction()-detail) and parse string in `$db` and convert it to array with `Connection` configuration - `MigrateController` will be able to handle it.